# Converting Java class structure to yml file

Tags: java, json, yaml

I have a complex model class in `Java` that has attributes of different class. I wanted to get the schema of the class in yml format for better readability. I was able get the structure of the class to a JSON file but I feel that yml is less cluttered and easy to ready.

**Example**
**From**

```
public class Phone {
    public String name;
    public String number;
}
```

**To**

```
Phone:
    fields:
      name:
        type: String
      number:
        type: String
```

Comment: Did you try yamlbeans? sourceforge.net/projects/yamlbeans

Comment: Yes, I tried it. But it does not have API's to covert a class . It can read objects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Jackson library offers the ability to generate a JSONSchema from a Java class. You should be able to serialize it into a YAML, although I haven't actually tested this part. Here how it might look like :

```
ObjectMapper m = new ObjectMapper();
SchemaFactoryWrapper visitor = new SchemaFactoryWrapper();
m.acceptJsonFormatVisitor(m.constructType(Phone.class), visitor);
JsonSchema jsonSchema = visitor.finalSchema();

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
mapper.writeValue(yamlFile, jsonSchema);
```

You may need this configuration if you use enums

```
mapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.WRITE_ENUMS_USING_TO_STRING, true);
```

More details at the github page of the [Yaml module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-yaml) and the [JSON schema module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-jsonSchema)

Comment: I do not want to convert the object, I need to read the class and get its schema. This code just printed the class name and did not detect any attributes

Comment: Yes the above approach will serialize an object. Jackson has a schema generator for JSON. I'll modify my answer

Comment: Thanks, yes it worked. But the only cry here is the yml output becomes as cryptic as JSON. Converting to JSON puts the ref, urn attributes.These are carried over while converting to yml file. Anyways accepting the answer as others may benefit this. If you have any ideas to get the clean conversion, please update this answer

Answer (score 1):

## From RAM to File

If your use case is to just serialize your existing objects, without reading them first, you might try the approach from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46447267/5108777) using Jackson; it just writes to a file an `example` object.

```
// Create an ObjectMapper mapper for YAML
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());

// Write object as YAML file
mapper.writeValue(new File("/path/to/yaml/file"), example);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try http://jyaml.sourceforge.net/
The project is no longer active though.

Answer (score 0):

An other approach may be the read the class files using the ASM library. It has a nice visitor API which lets you fairly simply transform the bytecode into an other representation like YAML (start here: http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/ClassVisitor.html ). But it might be an overkill for your task.