# Writing Java object instance to YAML using Jackson

Tags: java, jackson, yaml, jackson2, jackson-modules

I have a 'Example' Pojo class as mentioned below.
Can any one tel to save instance of Example class to YAML file using Jackson.

```
public class Example {

String name;
int value;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(int value) {
    this.value = value;
}
```

}

Comment: Just saying, SnakeYaml can do this on its own and you have more control over it than when using Jackson. If Jackson is not a requirement, drop it and use SnakeYaml directly.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Jackson has a [module that supports YAML](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-text/tree/master/yaml). Ensure that you add the [required dependency](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-text/tree/master/yaml#maven-dependency) to your project, then you can use it as following:

```java
// Create an ObjectMapper mapper for YAML
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());

// Write object as YAML file
mapper.writeValue(new File("/path/to/yaml/file"), example);
```

Alternatively you can write your object as a string:

```
// Write object as YAML string
String yaml = mapper.writeValueAsString(example);
```

Comment: when I use this code, it add a line in first of file ( comment line as ---)?? how can remove this fist line?

Comment: @M2E67 Try `ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory().disable(Feature.WRITE_DOC_START_MARKER));`. See the [documentation](http://static.javadoc.io/com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-yaml/2.9.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/yaml/YAMLGenerator.Feature.html#WRITE_DOC_START_MARKER).